# Linkedin экспортировать рекламные компании через API

Tags: node.js, linkedin, linkedin-api

Честно, относительно весьма много времени потратил.

В LinkedIn есть рекламные компании (https://www.linkedin.com/ad/accounts/)

Если зайти в компанию, там есть много "рекламных объявлений". А так же есть возможность все это добро экспортировать в csv...

Хочу с помощью апи экспортировать... но это потрясающее апи... я никак не могу найти, что-кто-куда.

Я создал приложение, дал права rw_company_admin, получил токен, смог посмотреть общую статистику по компаниям... но мне нужен отчет по эффективности рекламных объявлений

Пробовал https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-linkedin, на доку не смотрите, только в исходниках есть все методы.
И все равно не нашел нужных...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Linkedin не позволяет получить нужные данные. Поэтому самый простой способ, это:

1. Авторизироваться с помощью phantom.js и забрать куки (хотя достаточно только li_at, но я все куки забираю)
2. Прямо со старинцы, из исходного кода забрать все кампании (phantom.js уже не нужен, просто curl)
3. Сделать экспорт (тоже только curl)
4. Распарсить csv (npm: csvtojson)

Microsoft умные люди, они не будут пользоваться своим API. Мы тоже не будем :)